# React JS - call function however you get to a page/component

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a page fetching data and then showing a list of results. I have a main App component with a navbar and 3 possible sub-pages. The first is the home, where you can also do a research as i mentioned. When you do that, i made it so that the beginning of the list scrolls to the top of the browser window (banner, navbar and such get out of the screen, on the top). Now, if you click one of the results, you get to a detailed page about that.
What i'm trying to achieve is to call the page scroll i mentioned also when you get back to the home, by using "previous page" button or even by clicking home in the navbar. The results list is still there, so i want to scroll it again on the top.
The function i use for the scroll is

```
  const scrollPage = () => {
    setTimeout(function () {
    const element = document.getElementById("comment");
    element.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: "smooth",
      block: "start",
    });
  }, 1000); }
```

and this works when i do the research, since i call it inside the search function. i tried calling the same function with useEffect() but it didn't work, also i tried like

```
useEffect(() => {
window.addEventListener('load', scrollPage);
return () => { 
  window.removeEventListener('load', scrollPage);
 }}, []);
```

but it doesn't work. if i click home in the navbar it goes on top of the page and if i use the "previous page" button i get back at the same Y of the list and the beginning of the list doesn't get scrolled.

Comment: The event `"load"` is probably not dispatched and that's why it doesn't call the function. Why don't you just rely on `useEffect` when the component updates: `useEffect(() => { scrollPage() }, []);`?

Comment: as i said, i tried that but doesn't work. also, to make it clear, useEffect is inside App. i have to. with react routes i'm hardcoding the content of the page instead of calling components, i have to do that since some things wouldn't work otherwise. so, basically, i need to call the scroll when some content in App gets shown/loaded.

Comment: Oh, I misread that. I don't know of your project structure, but depending on how it's implemented there are a few way. If you for example update `location.href` on tab change you could rely on `"popstate"` even listener instead. Other solution would be to create a local state like `const [activePage, setActivePage] = useState(0);` where you'd keep currently active subpage index/name. You'd then call `setActivePage()` on page click and make `useEffect` to depend on `activePage`

Comment: nice idea, i have to try that!